# Stop images from flashing on AJAX get requests

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following functions which refresh my page every 10 seconds and grab some data from the database, and places it in some divs. The problem is, if there are images, they flash every 10 seconds as the area is refreshed.

Is there some way I can prevent this flashing of images? Perhaps some form of caching or preloading?

The images are hosted at S3 and I'm using PHP for the project.

Thanks in advance!

```
function refreshAll() {
  var doneCount = 0;
  var onDone = function() {
    doneCount++;

    if (doneCount == 2)
      setTimeout(refreshAll, 10000);
        console.log("fetching new updates....");
  }

  loadLeaderboard(onDone);
  loadActivity(onDone);
 }

refreshAll();

function loadLeaderboard(onDone) {
   var competitionId = $("body").attr("data-competitionId");
   var url = "leaderboard_api.php?competitionId=" + competitionId;

   $.get(url, function(data) {
     $("#leaderboard-spot").html(data);

      if (onDone)
        onDone();

   });
 }

function loadActivity(onDone) {
  var competitionId = $("body").attr("data-competitionId");
  var url = "activity_api.php?competitionId=" + competitionId;

   $.get(url, function(data) {
     $("#activityspot").html(data);
        if (onDone)
        onDone();
   });
 }
```

Comment: Is it due to the fact that you are replacing the content of the entire leaderboard-spot? instead of just updating the changed divs inside leaderboard?

Comment: Yes in this case the entire activity-spot. I believe that is the problem. How could I only replace the changes?

Comment: You would have to parse your incoming data and somehow compare with your current DOM.

Comment: Yep, sounds like what I need to do. The googling begins!